# WHAT CODE to Create a Trigger. Payment Confirmation will Trigger a DB FORM Submit Button

Tags: javascript, json, triggers

My site is a `WIX` website and it will have a Database.

Customers fill out a Data form. **Before** the form is submitted to the database, they must then fill out a Payment Form.

Then the payment is sent for Confirmation. What I need is some sort of **trigger** that when the payment returns confirmation, it should trigger the form submission to the database.

Is the trigger term the correct direction for this ?  What would the code look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I guess you should use the `then` like this:

```
functionThatSendsPayment().then(() => submitForm())
```

`then` will only be executed if the `functionThatSendsPayment` returns a valid response.
Similar to `then`, `catch` block is executed when the function returns an error.